# What does n mean in .readframes(n)? - wave Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

According to the [wave documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html), it explains "Reads and returns at most n frames of audio, as a bytes object." How does the number of frames affect the audio that is being played? What is then the best number to assign to n?

```
Wave_read.readframes(n)
```

I've tried assigning various numbers, but the sound quality seemed the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the number of frames affect the audio that is being played?

There is no affect on the quality of the audio being played, if that's what you're getting at. Quality is affected by the frame rate (sampling rate), sample width and the number of channels. These parameters affect the number of frames that comprise the data portion of the wav file.

Each frame contains [`getsampwidth()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getsampwidth) * [`getnchannels()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.getnchannels) bytes. The duration of the audio file in seconds will be the total number of frames divided by the frame rate:

```
with wave.open('audio.wav') as wf:
    print(f'duration: {wf.getnframes() / wf.getframerate():.2f} seconds')
```

The number of frames per second is given by `wf.getframerate()`. You can use this to work out how many frames to read. If, for example, you wanted to buffer up 1 seconds worth of audio you would read `wf.getframerate()` samples:

```
with wave.open('audio.wav') as wf:
    one_second_audio = wf.readframes(wf.getframerate())
```

> What is then the best number to assign to n?

This is probably determined by how large a buffer you want to maintain for your player. You probably want to buffer a few seconds worth and keep replenishing it as the audio is played. In this case `n` would be determined by the number of seconds to read multiplied by the frame rate as discussed above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Just to clarify, n refers to the no. of frames you want to read (Buffer), and what it affects is just the time taken to read?

Comment: Yes, `n` is the number of frames to read. The more you read the longer it will take, however, the timings that I talked about are to do with how the amount of data read relates the the duration of the audio that you can play. So, to play 1 second of the audio file would require that you read `n` where `n` is the frame rate.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!!